# ToolStripComboBox + objects default string value

Tags: vb.net, toolstripcombobox

I am using a ToolStripComboBox to list some data. I am populating this combo with some custom objects:

```
For Each obj As myObject In myObjectList
    myToolStripComboBox.Items.Add(obj)
Next
```

This works great except the text displayed in the combo is the name of the object class.  I can understand why and realise that I need to do something to make the combo use a property from my class instead.

The help files state:

> To add objects to the list at run
>   time, assign an array of object
>   references with the AddRange method.
>   **The list then displays the default
>   string value for each object.** You can
>   add individual objects with the Add
>   method.

The bit in bold suggests I need to setup the *default string value* in my class.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an Overrides ToString to your myObject class :

```
Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    --return whatever you want to display
End Function
```